# SQL CONVERT_IMPLICIT and speed of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, epicor10

Boss had a query joining a TranGLC table to our Invoiced table. The transaction table is set up in a way there the key fields are varchar fields labeled as Key1, Key2, etc. with a qualifier for each record in terms of what table the row joins with. So TranGLC.RelatedTo = 'InvcDtl', Key1 and Key2 are Invoice Number and Line Number (stored as Ints in other tables). RelatedTo could be one of many things.

The query itself ran in about 9 seconds, but when the bossman put in a 'Where OrderNumber = XXXXXX' which should return fewer records, it took 48 seconds to run. Odd. He brought it to me and looking at the execution plan, I started playing and found that TranGLC was implicitly converting Key1 and Key2 to an int to match up with the Invoice Table.

I tried Explicitly converting InvoiceNumber and Line to varchar fields and BAM! Ran in less than a second. ex.

```
Inner Join InvoiceDtl on TGLC.Key1 = convert(varchar(25), InvoiceDtl.InvoiceNum) and.....
```

The execution plan is different, but I'm afraid this is where my knowledge of such things stalls into guesswork. I'm curious as to why this is and how it affects performance so drastically. My theory is that since the TranGLC table holds SO many more records (many of which could not be converted to integers anyways) that the Implicit Conversion tries (and fails in a lot of cases) to convert the whole Key columns of TranGLC first, then join int to int Vs taking significantly fewer fields, with no problems converting to varchars, and then joining varchar to varchar.

Anyone have a detailed explanation? Query for context:

```
select 
            [TranGLC].[GLAccount] as [TranGLC_GLAccount],
            [InvcDtl].[InvoiceNum] as [InvcDtl_InvoiceNum],
            [InvcDtl].[OrderNum] as [InvcDtl_OrderNum],
            (SUM(TranGLC.CreditAmount)) as [Calculated_GROSS],
            (SUM(TranGLC.DebitAmount)) as [Calculated_DISCOUNT],
            (SUM(TranGLC.CreditAmount)-SUM(TranGLC.DebitAmount)) as [Calculated_NET]
from Erp.TranGLC as TranGLC
inner join Erp.InvcDtl as InvcDtl on 
            TranGLC.Company = InvcDtl.Company
            and TranGLC.Key1 = convert(varchar(25),InvcDtl.InvoiceNum)
            and TranGLC.Key2 = convert(varchar(4),Invcdtl.InvoiceLine)
            and TranGLC.RelatedToFile = 'InvcDtl'

where (TranGLC.TranDate >= '1-1-2016'  and TranGLC.TranDate <= convert(date, getdate()) and InvcDtl.OrderNum = 123456)
group by [TranGLC].[GLAccount],
            [InvcDtl].[InvoiceNum],
            [InvcDtl].[OrderNum]
```

[image: WithConvert]

[image: WithoutConvert]

Comment: SQL is all about scalar... if you want to compare something then that has to be of the same type and length otherwise will be another step for the parser to go through... even your `TranDate > = '1-1-2016'` that should be `casted` as date to avoid additional parsing.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  The engine is trying to convert, and failing, on many of your keys when performing the JOIN.  By explicitly converting the smaller set of values you sped up the query.  Tbh your data relation model is pretty fouled up if you have a foreign key to a table that is of a different type than the value in the table.  It's going to create a lot of similar headaches for you.

Comment: "The engine is trying to convert, and failing" is wrong. If it really failed, the query could not execute at all throwing error. If it not failed it means that for the filter the query has there are no rows that have keys that cannot be converted to int

Comment: To answer your question we need both the plans, please update your question pasting these plans. It's always the matter of wrong or good cardinality estimation, and explicit conversion reraly can improve it. The best practice is to have the fields for join of the same type, otherwise cardinality estimation often is wrong

Comment: I agree that the relation for this table is not how most would've done it. It's not one we made, it's just the way it is for this software.

Sepupic, I added the execution plans. New (quicker) one first. If I was pulling in every tran record I think it would fail since I can't convert something like 'Tuna145' to an int. But the records I'm joining to are all convertible to an integer, so it succeeds. But what I was getting at is I think it was trying to do the conversion to every tran record before rather than the new way, which is converting the smaller amount of records the other way.

Comment: Which is obviously wrong. Yes everything displayed after the query filter can convert to an int, so its succeeding. Leaving me wondering why it takes so much longer one way vs the other.